# Watanabe–Akaike/widely applicable information criterion (WAIC) using PyMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

Does anyone know how to calculate WAIC in a PyMC model? Several review papers suggest that it requires sampling from the predictive density, which is relatively straightforward in PyMC, so can WAIC be calculated easily too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function:

```python
def waic(trace, model=None):
     """
     Calculate the widely available information criterion of the samples in trace from model.
     """
     model = pm.modelcontext(model)

     log_py = []
     for obs in model.observed_RVs:
         log_py.append([obs.logp_elemwise(pt) for pt in trace ])
     log_py = np.hstack(log_py)

     lppd =  np.sum(np.log(np.mean(np.exp(log_py), axis=0)))

     p_waic = np.sum(np.var(log_py, axis=0))

     return -2 * lppd + 2 * p_waic
```

That will be soon part of PyMC3.